# I want to add table structure in drop down list

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I want to add two colums from my database table into a drop-down list.

I have a **fruits** table in my database, and I want to fetch the name of the fruit and it's quantity from the database and insert it into my select drop-down list. But it should be in an option tag, and it should be in table structure.

```
<select  id="availableFruits" name="availableFruits" multiple size=7 style="width:auto;float:left;" >
    <?php  $fruitList=$this->fruitList;
        foreach ($fruitList as $key => $val) 
        {
    printf('<option value="%s"><table><tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr></table></option>',$val,$val,$val);
    //printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $val, $val);
        }  ?>
</select>
```

This is my code for the drop-down list which I have written in my HTML. Here I am dynamically adding the fruit's name and quantity in the drop-down list, but it's not printing it in a table structure.

The structure should be like:

```
 <option value="%s"><table><tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr></table></option>
```

Comment: Last I checked, `SELECT` Boxes could not display tables inside them. Guess you are pushing `SELECT` too hard here

Comment: Actually I want to display list of fruit name and fruit quantity in one list. Then user will select one row (fruit) which he want to buy. then only fruit name will be added to another list.

Answer (score 1):

For that Better to use Jquery plugin, to display the Dropdown as per your Choice

May the below link would help you
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add html elements in `<option>`

Comment: Of course it's possible with pure html and css. Just not inside an option block

Comment: @tlenss I think that is what we are talking about and my statement is about that only.. of course I know how to create tables with html and css

Comment: You are forgetting the key element in your answer 'option'. That's why i replied. It's not quite clear!

Comment: I have gone through w3schools.com  , I found that we can add table inside select tag. but i really don't no how to do it in my code.because here i have used foreach loop . Please help me